# Do you know how I can get this function to produce the correct result?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The function below is supposed to calculate user's answers to questions.

If the user hasn't take the test, show a message that the user hasn't taken the test.

If the user's answer is between 0% and 75%, let the user know s/he doesn't meet minimum requirement.

If the user's score is greater than 75%, then user has passed.

Problem is that if the user's score is 0, then user gets a message that s/he hasn't taken the test and this wrong.

Any idea how I can correct this?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
Public Function getStatus(ByVal value As Object) As String
    Dim myRow As FormViewRow = scoreGridView.Row
    Dim Message As String = ""
    Dim lbscore As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("PercentLabel"), Label)
    If Decimal.Parse(value) >= 0 AndAlso Decimal.Parse(value) < 75 Then
        Message = "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Your score does not meet minimum requirement</span>"
    ElseIf Decimal.Parse(value) >= 75 Then
        Message = "<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold'>Congratulations you have passed the test!</span>"
    Else
        Message = "You have not yet taken the test for this survey"
    End If
    Return Message
End Function
```

Comment: Set value to NULL or Empty when the user hasn't taken the test.  Check for that first, then do your decimal parsing tests...  If you expect the string "0" to mean two things, you're in a world of hurt.  ("" can mean something different)

Comment: Ask yourself, what does zero mean? Hasn't taken the test or test taken but scored zero? ^^ The first comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I would have checked it as useful answer just to show my appreciation.

These things are subjective judgement calls and I chose Karl's solution as the best solution but that doesn't mean the rest aren't good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `d` literal suffix for your values to ensure they are compared as `Decimal` types, like this:

```
Public Function getStatus(ByVal value As Object) As String
    Dim myRow As FormViewRow = scoreGridView.Row
    Dim Message As String = ""
    Dim lbscore As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("PercentLabel"), Label)
    If Decimal.Parse(value) >= 0d AndAlso Decimal.Parse(value) < 75d Then
        Message = "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Your score does not meet minimum requirement</span>"
    ElseIf Decimal.Parse(value) >= 75d Then
        Message = "<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold'>Congratulations you have passed the test!</span>"
    Else
        Message = "You have not yet taken the test for this survey"
    End If
    Return Message
End Function
```

Altenatively, for checking against zero (decimal), you can use the `Decimal.Zero`, like this:

```
If Decimal.Parse(value) >= Decimal.Zero AndAlso Decimal.Parse(value) < 75d Then
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.

AND many thanks to all those who contributed to my question.

Answer (score 2):

what are you trying to achieve?

Base in your code it will return "Your score does not meet minimum requirement" when the value is 0.

and returning "You have not yet taken the test for this survey" if the value is  < 0.